# How to add Pine Script to TradingView Widget?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm using this (https://www.tradingview.com/widget/advanced-chart/) widget at this moment. And trying to add my own created PineScript on Graph but have failed so far?

Do you know any method to achieve desired outcome? I'm using NextJS but your solution cane be in or without any framework.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.